# Auto Mapper - Is their any way so auto mapper can identify Model and DTO has same definition then no need to provide Mapping definition for the same?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Auto Mapper 10.1.1.0 version.

I am looking for any property or any other way to set something in Automapper so When I have same definition for Model and DTO class then I don't need to provide it Explicitly.

For Example

**Model Class**

```
Public Class1
{
 property1
 property2
 property3
}
```

**DTO Class**

```
Public Class1
{
 property1
 property2
 property3
}
```

Both Model class CLASS1 and DTO class CLASS1 has same definition
though if I dont create mapping between those class it gives error in missing mapping.

So I have to provide map in register method

Like

```
private static void ExampleRegisters(IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
{
     config.CreateMap<DataAccess.Models.CLASS1, DTO.CLASS1>();
}
```

I am looking for way to avoid writting this mapping line.

```
     config.CreateMap<DataAccess.Models.CLASS1, DTO.CLASS1>();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. AutoMapper already does map properties with the same name automatically. If it does not show us the code you have.

Comment: I am looking for any option at class level. Not for property lavel. Example I have Model Class1 and DTO Class1. Both class has same set of properties. Still I have to provide mapping definition like config.CreateaMap<Model.Class1,DTO.Class1>();

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate on the problem you have. Provide a MCVE which shows the problem you have.

Comment: It should be easy to create all those default maps using reflection, Assembly.GetTypes or smth similar.

Comment: @HarmonicaBlower Could you please provide me example so that i can implement in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can find these types like this:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Mappings));
        var types = assembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var props = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var pairings = types.Where(t => t.GetProperties()
                    .Any(p => p.Name == prop.Name && p.PropertyType == prop.PropertyType) && t != type);

                // you can loop over pairings to create mappings
            }
        }
```

and then use them to create the mappings. I think it's a little bit of an overkill, though and you'd be better off declaring the maps yourself, unless neccessary.